# Почему отсутствует дизайнер в списке программ после установки?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, python-3.8

Работаю на ОС Windows 7, python 3.8.10. Установил PyQt5 с помощью команды `pip install pyqt5`, но в списке программ дизайнер не появился.

Что не так?

Comment: Пакет pyqt5 не содержит дизайнер. Один из ответов на аналогичный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42090739/4752653) подсказывает, что нужно устанавливать pyqt5-tools. Либо скачивайте дизайнер отдельно.

Comment: поставил тулс командой pip install pyqt5-tools так же дизайнер не отражается в списке программ.

Comment: "Список программ" - это что у Вас?

Comment: Меню пуск все программы. Это согласно инструкциям с разных сайтов если подскажите как его запустить без этого буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась с помощью поиска по диску С: с условием designer.exe